# HTTP POST Request with PHP + cURL

Tags: c#, php, curl

I am trying to create HTTP post request using PHP + cURL that is equivalent to the example mentioned [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Toast-Notification-Sample-fb20ae13/sourcecode?fileId=62823&pathId=792575524) of file "SendToast.aspx.cs"

My PHP file looks like this below,

```
<?php 

$uri      = $_POST["uri"];
$title    = $_POST["title"]; 
$subtitle = $_POST["subtitle"];


$file = 'file.txt';
//phpinfo();
$theData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\\r';
$theData .= "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">";
$theData .=  "<wp:Toast>";
$theData .=  "<wp:Text1>" .$title;
$theData .=  "</wp:Text1>";
$theData .=  "<wp:Text2>" .$subtitle;
$theData .=  "</wp:Text2>";
$theData .= "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>";
$theData .= "</wp:Toast>";
$theData .= "</wp:Notification>";   

$header_array = array('X-WindowsPhone-Target' => 'toast','X-NotificationClass' => '2','Content-type:' => 'text/xml','Content-length:' => strlen($theData));
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header_array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$theData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//print_r($ch);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
//echo $server_outout;
//curl_close ($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) 
{ 
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch); 
}
else 
{ 
 // Show me the result 
    print $server_output; 
    curl_close($ch); 
} 
//file_put_contents($file, $theData);
```

?>

can anyone tell me what i m doing wrong here?, i also tried to use HTTPRequest Class to create this example, but i had hard time configuring php_http.dll extension, it seems the file has either dependencies or its corrupt. nevertheless help on this one would be great.

Comment: Could you please let us know the errors or incorrect behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: sorry buddy, but i am not much familiar with php output functions, what i can tell is, if everything works fine it shall send notification to my phone app (the ASP example works perfectly and it sends notification, means phoneapp is ok to receive), the server_output variable does not return anything, its blank, or may be i dont know how to exactly print it, can you hint me how can i print error codes or response data? that would be very helpful

Comment: You forgot to url-encode POST data: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($theData));

Comment: Thank,s let me try that.

Comment: tried url-encode, but no change, :-(

Comment: Try remove `'Content-type:' => 'text/xml'` from `$header_array`

Comment: it seems adding one more option "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);" seems to be helpful, atleast now the server says my message is received, its still not delivered to phone but server responded in OK. thank you guys for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the http header(`$header_array`) in a wrong way. Use this one.

```
$header_array = array(
  'X-WindowsPhone-Target: toast',
  'X-NotificationClass: 2',
  'Content-type: text/xml'
);
```

If this doesn't work then change the `text/xml` into `application/xml` from above.

Comment: yes, from various examples i learnt that. anyways, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

try to USE `urlencode` and prepare the variable for POST first

```
$postedfield="MYPOST=".urlencode($theData);
```

and then use this variable

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postedfield);
```

and decode the posted value

Comment: break your problem in pieces. first try without any header and try to output the variable in text. and if it is being output then you might need to format in valid xml to let C# understand the reques